# magento enterprise admin category drag and drop is not working?

Tags: php, jquery, magento

In magento enterprise version. 1.14.1.0 ,I want to sort manually the categories order (categories - manage categories), when the page is ready, I do drag and drop with the category but after ajax saved if i refresh the page the order is not working properly, I look around but i don't have find nothing.
 I try also, tried to re index data but nothing change, why don't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use f12/right click inspect console and reload the category page. Check to see if you have javascript errors as the drag and drop functionality uses Prototype heavily.

You likely have some output in your index.php or javascript clash.

Comment: I have same problem. No javascript errors. It even returns a "SUCCESS" response but when I reload categories page it remains with old sorting. Magento CE, not EE.

Comment: Check your error logs please. Specifically root/var/logs/exception.log and system.log and if they're disabled enable them in system->configuration->developer If nothing shows there check apache logs and post anything relevant that doesn't pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I could not find any error, neither magento logs nor server logs. I got some database timeouts when changing it position, but even when it seemed to do it correctly it didn't. I have disabled drag and drop functionality temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Finally success,there was not any error in magento coding level.Actually we were importing category via csv file,there was a field name 'position' ,we have fill this field with sorting numbers according to category position.

Cheers.

Comment: Not my case unfortunately as I'm not importing categories.